# Connect two networks via an iMac?

Tags: networking, router, mac, ip, ethernet

Ohai guys. I have a question regarding a setup and as a fresh trainee, I am having problems since there is barely any information on the internet let alone a similar case.

The current setup:

- 2 networks, lets call them 40.xxx.xxx.xxx and 50.xxx.xxx.xxx
- one computer (and to be specific: an iMac) which is currently only connected to the 50.xxx.xxx.xxx network
- TV screens with Apple TVs, which can only be connected to the 40.xxx.xxx.xxx network due to physical limitations

**Goal:** To be able to access all Apple TVs from the 50.xxx.xxx.xxx network. In my case, we have software on the Apple TVs which allows presenting slides for commercials on the TV screens, so it's basically just uploading files to the Apple TVs I guess.

**Limitation:** The 40.xxx.xxx.xxx network, the one the Apple TVs are on, is being provided by an external company for guests (Free WiFi) at our location and based on that a router isn't an option.

**Idea**: The iMac needs to stay connected to the 50.xxx.xxx.xxx network. The idea was the also connect it to the 40.xxx.xxx.xxx network and do some ROUTE ADD to let the iMac act like a router.

With that being said, I'm running into following unanswered questions:
AFAIK the ROUTE ADD command only works if the iMac is connected to the

- 50.xxx.xxx.xxx network via LAN and the the 40.xxx.xxx.xxx network with WLAN
  or
- to both 50.xxx.xxx.xxx and 40.xxx.xxx.xxx network via LAN

is that right?

Don't I need in the second case a second NIC for the iMac because the iMac itself only has one ethernet port?

Is this even doable or did I read bs on the internet?

If it is, shouldn't it be possible to have any device on the 50.xxx.xxx.xxx network to communicate with the Apple TVs with the iMac acting as a router?

If it isn't doable, is there any solution to this?

Comment: Is connecting to the 40 network via wired Ethernet possible? Or is it Wi-Fi only?

Answer (score 0):

## Three things to note:

1. Fortunately, connecting the iMac to both networks and making it route between the two should be easy.
2. Unfortunately, getting the Apple TVs and other devices to know about and use that route will probably be hard. So your iMac will be ready to route, but no one will actually send it any traffic for it to forward to the other network, so it will be as if it's not there at all. It sounds like you don't have admin access to the DHCP servers and routers on both networks, which limits your options even further.
3. Also unfortunately, most LAN-based service discovery protocols are based on multicasts or broadcasts that aren't forwarded across routers, so whatever software you wanted to use to send your video/slides/pictures/whatever to the Apple TVs, might not be able to find the Apple TVs from the other subnet.

Without knowing more about which options are or are not available to you, it's hard for me to advise you on #2 and #3. So let me tell you how to do #1:

## Setting up IP forwarding (basic routing) on your iMac

If you can get wired Ethernet access to both networks, You can add an Ethernet interface to your iMac by either adding an Apple Thunderbolt GigE dongle, or a third party USB 3 GigE dongle, or if you don't care about performance, and Apple USB 2 10/100 Ethernet dongle. By the way, if your iMac happens to be an iMac Pro, it already has two Ethernets (both capable of up to 10G).

If one of the networks is only accessible via Wi-Fi, you're still fine. Just connect to that network via Wi-Fi, and use Ethernet to connect to the other network.

For best results, give your iMac a static IP address on both networks.

To enable packet forwarding (routing) between the two networks, run this command:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

To automatically enable packet forwarding on every reboot, do this:

```
sudo echo "net.inet.ip.forwarding=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

(That appends the line "net.inet.ip.forwarding=1" to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf. If that file doesn't exist, it will be created.)

So now you've got your iMac ready to forward (route) packets between the two networks, but we still haven't solved problems 2 and 3.

## Ideas for solving problem 2 (advertising the route)

There are lots of different ways to solve problem 2 (getting devices to know about the route), but it's hard to know which would be right for you. Here are some possibilities:

1. If you have admin access to the other routers on both networks, you could enter static routes on them to know about your iMac's route. Then you could make sure they do ICMP Redirects to get devices to talk directly to your iMac when they need to use that route.
2. If the other routers support a route advertisement protocol, you might be able to run a route advertising daemon on your Mac to advertise your route.
3. If you control the DHCP servers on both networks, you can have those networks list your iMac as the default route for both networks. Then have your iMac have static routes for the original routers on both networks. Come to think of it, this might be very tricky to handle, because you need a way to make sure the rest of net-40's traffic is routed to net-40's router, and that the rest of net-50's  traffic is routed to net-50's router. You sort of need two default routes, based on which subnet the packet came from, and I'm not sure how to set that up.
4. There are more possibilities I could go into, but they seem less and less likely to be a good solution for you.

As for problem 3 (service discovery across a router) I think I'd first want to verify whether or not the software they're using to send their stuff to the Apple TVs really requires service discovery to work. And if so, what service discovery protocol it uses. It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing that.